# Does VS 2010 Publish exclude schema files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publish

I have a schema file in a asp.net mvc 2.0 application that is a .net 4.0

I am using visual studios 2010 ultimate and I am using their publish button.

When I publish my solution the folder that contains my xml schema gets excluded. I don't know why it's doing this but I don't want this to happen. Is there a setting I can set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the file properties of your .xsd to ensure they're part of the build and publish. They'll need to be marked as **Content**. The sub-directory needs no modification, just the .xsd.

```
Properties -> Build Action -> Content.
```

[image]

Perform a publish operation, and your folder and .xsd are included in the publish artifacts. In this test, I published to a local directory named mvc-test-output. All MVC output and the .xsd and its subdirectory were published.

[image]